# Storing Results of a Operation in a Matrix

Tags: matlab, function, vector

Let's say I want to take the sin of 1 through 100 (in degrees).

I come from a C background so my instinct is to loop 1 through 100 in a for loop (something I can do in Matlab). In a matrix/vector/array I would store sin(x) where x is the counter of the for loop.

I cannot figure out how to do this in Matlab. Do I create a array like

```
x = [1 .. 100];
```

And then do

```
x[offset] = numberHere;
```

I know the "correct" way. For operations like addition you use .+ instead of + and with a function like sin I'm pretty sure you just do

```
resultArray = sin(x);
```

I just want to know that I *could* do it the C way in case that ever came up, thus my question here on SO. :)

Comment: + doesn't need a "." before it for element-wise math, just * and / and ^ for multiplication/division/exponentiation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have already pointed out there are for-loops in MATLAB as well.

```
help for
```

should give you everything you need about how it works. The difference from C is that the loop  can go over objects and not only an integer:

```
objects = struct('Name', {'obj1', 'obj2'}, 'Field1', {'Value1','Value2'});
for x = objects
   disp(sprintf('Object %s Field1 = %d', x.Name, x.Field1))
end
```

That example will output:

```
Object obj1 Field1 = Value1
Object obj2 field1 = Value2
```

This could have been done as

```
for i=1:length(objects)
   x = objects(i);
   disp(sprintf('Object %s Field1 = %d', x.Name, x.Field1))
end
```

And now to what I really wanted to say: **If you ever write a for loop in MATLAB, stop and think!**. For most tasks you can vectorize the code so that it uses matrix operations and builtin functions instead of looping over the data. This usually gives a **huge speed gain**. It is not uncommon that vectorized code executes 100x faster than looping code. Recent versions of MATLAB has JIT compilation which makes it less dramatic than before, but still: **Always vectorize if you can**.

Answer (score 6):

```
% vectorized
x = sin((1:100)*pi/180);
```

or

```
% nonvectorized
x=[];
for i = 1:100
   x(i) = sin(i*pi/180);
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I beleive this can actually be done as a one liner in MatLab:

```
x = sind(1:100);
```

Note that you use sind() instead of sin(). Sin() takes radians as arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, if understand correctly you want a loop  like structure

```
resultArray = zeros(1,length(x)) %% initialization aint necessary I just forgot how you dynamically add members :x
for i = 1:length(x) %% starts with 1 instead of zero
   resultArray(i) = sin(x(i))
end
```

Warning I didn't test this but it should be about right.

Comment: Ah. So the offset operator is () instead of []. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, [] is used to define an array or a matrix. For example A=[1 3;2 4] will make a matrix which shows how are elements indexed A(3)=3, A(2)=2, etc.

Comment: You are missing an "end" in that for-loop. Also to append objects (which can be slow, mind you) just do: x(end+1) = new_value;

Answer (score 1):

@Daniel Fath

I think you'll need the final line to read

`resultArray(i) = sin(x(i))` (rather than x(1))

I think you can also do:

```
for i = x    
   ...
```

though that will behave differently if x is not a simple 1-100 vector